# R : How to fix plot.new has not been called yet

Tags: r, plot

I am aware this has been asked often but the other replies did not help with my specific problem.

I am trying to add these two plots together. [image: different parts of North Carolina] [image: Centroids of each region] to get this plot: [image: Map with centroids] for from https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf5.html.

The code used in this link is the following:

```
library(sf)
demo(nc, ask = FALSE, echo = FALSE)
plot(st_geometry(nc))

plot(st_geometry(nc), col = sf.colors(12, categorical = TRUE), border = 'grey', 
     axes = TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(st_centroid(nc)), pch = 3, col = 'red', add = TRUE)
```

but this is the error i get

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) :
plot.new has not been called yet
```

I am not sure what I should do to fix this. I tried to call `plot.new()` but that did not yield results.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. I get the expected plot and a warning "Warning message:
st_centroid assumes attributes are constant over geometries". R 4.2.3, sf 1.0-14. Windows 10.

Comment: Same over here on R 4.3.1, sf 1.0-14. Windows 10. Plot as expected.

Comment: try running `dev.off()` and rerunning the plot code?